# Image Upload Jquery Using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I upload an image using jQuery AJAX it gives me a status code of 200 but the image is not uploaded. When I try using Postman it works.

Can you tell me what's wrongs with my code. It doesn't show any errors but the image does not upload

```html
<div class="avatar-upload">
  <div class="avatar-edit">
    <input type='file' id="imageUpload" name="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
    <label for="imageUpload"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar-preview">
    <div id="imagePreview">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-all" id="btnImgaeUpload">Upload</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btnImgaeUpload", function() {
  var file_data = $('#imageUpload').prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('photo', file_data);

  $.ajax({
    url: api_url_https + '/customers/updateprofilepicture',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'ApiKey': api_key,
      'Platform': platform,
      'v': version,
      'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.token) === null ? '' : JSON.parse(localStorage.token)
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false, // Important!
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(userData) {
      if (userData.error === false) {
        localStorage.setItem('userPicture', JSON.stringify(userData.data.customer.picture));
      } else {}
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log(userData.error_messages[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: why are you `return false;` thats why the ajax is not executing.

Comment: Sorry For testing purpose I had put return false; now I remove also I remove from code.

Comment: And does it work now? Are there different errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan till it did not work and no error comes in the console log.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the AJAX request is being made successfully and the problem is in the server side logic which handles the request and stores the data. As you've not shown that, we can't really help you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but when I upload from postman it works the only when issuing in AJAX call

Answer (score -1):

Use `serialize()`

```js
$.ajax({
  url: api_url_https + '/customers/updateprofilepicture',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'ApiKey': api_key,
    'Platform': platform,
    'v': version,
    'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.token) === null ? '' : JSON.parse(localStorage.token)
  },
  method: 'POST',
  data: form_data.serialize(),
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  processData: false, // Important!
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(userData) {
    if (userData.error === false) {
      localStorage.setItem('userPicture', JSON.stringify(userData.data.customer.picture));
    } else {}
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log(userData.error_messages[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: This will not work for two reasons. One `serialize()` is not a method of a FormData object. Assuming you meant that the OP should use the jQuery `serialize()` method on a `form` element, then that won't work either as this form contains a binary file data, not just text which can be serialised. I'd suggest researching the topic.

Comment: Issues resolved it's my mistake headers I used 'Content-Type': 'application/json',

Comment: In that case it would be best to delete this question as it was a configuration problem